# Properties for internal stability of a discrete-time system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, dynamical-systems

These are two parts of a larger proof I'm working on, can't figure how i) implies ii) though.

Dynamic system:

$x_{(k+1)} = Ax_{k},  x(0)=x_0$

Where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} $ is a real constant matrix.

Properties:

i) All the eigenvalues of A are located on the open unit disc

ii) $\bigvee x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty ||x_{k}||^2 < +\infty$

I understand that the eigenvalues are bounded in the disc, and that ii) shows the system is finite and won't blow up, but I honestly just can't find a way to show that i) implies ii). Here are some other tidbits I have:

$x(k) = A^kx_{0}$

$A^k \backsim e^{At}$

$||A^k|| \leqq \beta |\lambda|^k$

$||e^{At}|| \leqq \beta e^{-\alpha t}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you want to look at is what happens to the norms of the vectors $x_k$ as you repeatedly apply the matrix you have. The largest eigenvalue will dominate the growth of these $x_k$ (simply because it is the biggest, and they are being multiplied together with each successive application). If this eigenvalue is $|\lambda_1|<1$, you have a geometric sequence.

You could go on to say that $\Sigma^\infty_{k=0} ||x_k||^2 \leq c||x_0||^2 \Sigma^\infty_{k=0}|\lambda_1|^k = c||x_0||^2 \frac{1}{1-|\lambda_1|} <\infty$

If you wanted to use your other tidbits, i'd identify $\beta$ with c and $\lambda$ with my $\lambda_1$

Comment: So in the case of a continuous-time system, the eigenvalues are all on the open left hand plane, but in discrete-time, they are in fact bounded where they are all < 1 - this is the assumption you're making? At that point, we have to imply that the system won't blow up, and hence your inequality? Is it technically a triangular inequality?

Comment: The eigenvalues live in the open unit disk, as you state, so their norms are all less than 1, yes. What exactly do you mean by triangular equality?

Comment: I had done a proof of the triangle inequality using Cauchy-Schwartz thm., and this looked slightly similar, except with sums instead of integrals, just wondering if that relationship would need to be considered at all.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Considered is a strong word, i think you have enough of the pieces without bringing any fancier tools in at this stage.

Comment: heh. Yes. I'll edit it.